# Getting Ognl:NoConversationPossible Error

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2, ognl

I'm Using Struts2 and JQGrid. From JQgrid, I'm Calling to Action class to return JSON data to load data for my Grid. Values are properly coming from Action class but value is not getting populate on my grid and i receives Ognl:NoConversationPossible Error on my Console.

Comment: I dont know why i'm getting this error. Can anyone help to resolve this?

Comment: Where did yo use the ognl? Struts2 uses a type conversion technique to translate objects to strings and back like JSON but using it in the struts tags. Do you have any of them?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply Roman C, No i haven't use OGNL intensionaly.

Comment: Please check with my pom.xml above. Im using struts2 tags lik s:select, sx:autocompleter etc.

Comment: Somewhere in your JSP code you are using values, and these values are treated as OGNL expressions by default according to OGNL syntax. The grid I'm not sure if it's mapped right to JSON result.

Comment: just i'm trying to do this.., http://shazsterblog.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-use-jqgrid-with-struts2-json.html

Comment: In the above link, he is telling that one action is to generate JSON result and another one is to populate the JSON result into JQGrid. But he haven't mention any interrelation between the two actions anywhere. so i haven't used the ListUsersAction. Is this the problem?

Comment: I posted my JSP page above.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly whats wrong with my code and from where it is affecting?

Comment: What's wrong with your code or his code, or workflow?

Comment: I have already told you what's wrong with your code according the error desc you provided. In another way you should had provide the action configuration.

Comment: Thanks Roman C, I resolved the issue by handling ognlexception on my action class. it is working now.